# AspNet Core CookieAuthentication with injected SessionStore

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

During migration of an ASPNetCore 1.1 Project to ASPNetCore 2.0, we stumbled upon a Problem with the Cookie-AuthN and its `SessionStore`.

*ASP.NET Core 1* allowed us to do something like that:

```
public void ConfigureServices(...) {
    Services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(...);
    Services.AddSingleton<DistributedCookieSessionStore>(); /// SQL based store
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory) {
    var cookieOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>>().Value;
    cookieOptions.SessionStore = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<DistributedCookieSessionStore>();

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
}
```

Messy, but doing its Job.

Now with *ASP.NET Core 2* `app.UseAuthentication()` does not have a signature allowing to modify the options, and I am not able to use DI, to get a hold of the session store.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After long search I came accross this discussion https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1338 where they mentioned `IPostConfigureOptions` interface. I put that together and this works for me:

1) Implement interface `IPostConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>`

```
public class PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>
{
    private readonly ITicketStore _ticketStore;

    public PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions(ITicketStore ticketStore)
    {
        _ticketStore = ticketStore;
    }

    public void PostConfigure(string name, CookieAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        options.SessionStore = _ticketStore;
    }
}
```

2) Register this implementation to the container in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method

`services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions>();`

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Major help!

Comment: I wish I could vote this up 10x. This is the only way I could get a SessionStore working with ASP.NET Identity 2.x + IdentityServer when securing resources with OIDC on the local IDP. Thank you!

Comment: @pvasek services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions>(); ==> i think should not use AddSingleton here