# Resolving Authentication services in .Net Core 2.0 with AutoFac

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm in the process of migrating a .Net Core 1.x project to .Net Core 2.0. One of the things that has changed is that Authentication is now configured in `ConfigureServices` during startup using extensions to `IServiceCollection`.

I have some custom services which are used in my authentication schemes, however the bulk of the DI registration is built using AutoFac (after this is called):

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Other .Net Services Registered
    services.AddTransient<ITicketStore, DistributedCacheTicketStore>(); 
    services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationEvents>();  

    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            //Other cookie options
            options.SessionStore = sp.GetService<ITicketStore>();
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            //Other OIDC options
            options.Events = sp.GetService<AuthenticationEvents>();
        });

    //Register application services with AutoFac
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    RegisterAutoFacTypes(builder);

    //Include services from .Net DI container
    builder.Populate(services);

    //Build and return the AutoFac container
    var container = builder.Build();
    return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
}
```

At the moment, I'm attempting to also register the dependencies of `DistributedCacheTicketStore` and `AuthenticationEvents` on the `IServiceCollection` to allow me to use them in my Authentication config, but this is getting messy and I'd much rather keep it in the AutoFac registration.

Is there a sensible way of refactoring this to keep these registrations in AutoFac, but still use `services.AddAuthentication()` before the AutoFac container is built?

Comment: For anyone else struggling with this answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47036122/977554