# Resolve type during service registration in ASP.NET Core 7.0 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, startup

I'm building a distributed `ITicketStore` and I was trying to reuse the `IDistributedCache` through constructor injection:

```
public sealed class RedisTicketStore: ITicketStore 
{
    public RedisTicketStore(IDistributedCache cache, TimeSpan slidingExpiration) 
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Now, I'm assuming the answer is no, but is there any way for me to resolve the `IDependencyCache` type from within the `AddCookie` method?

```
builder.Services....
       .AddCookie( options => {
                                  ....
                                  options.SessionStore = resolve_my_RedisTicketStore
       });
```

For now, I'm creating a global `RedisCache` instance which is then registered as a singleton, but this is something which I really don't like:

```
RedisCache _cache = ...;
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDistributedCache>(_cache);
```

So, is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914143/aspnet-core-cookieauthentication-with-injected-sessionstore

Comment: Hello. Yes, perfect. Would you mind adding it as answer so that I can mark it as a solution? Thanks.

Comment: If the code provided in the linked question can be used as is, I recommend closing this question as a duplicate of that question.